# How do I change a form name attribute to something else?

Tags: forms, 6

I'm using a Drupal 6 custom form, and I want to change the form name attribute to something else. Is this possible?

For example, I have this.

```
<input type="text" name="field" maxlength="128" id="edit-name" value="">
```

I want to change it to the following.

```
<input type="text" data-name="field" maxlength="128" id="edit-name" value="">
```

Comment: **[On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for the info. But I want to know is this possible or not

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove the `name` attribute. But you can add a data-attribute by using hook_form_alter:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'myform') {
    $form['myfield']['#attributes']['data-name'] = 'value';
  }
}
```

If it is a form you made yourself with Form API, then you can just do it in the form builder function:

```
$form['myfield'] = array(
  // properties...
  '#attributes' => array(
    'data-name' => 'value',
  )
);
```